# count book per member in current and history

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I go about writing this query? I'm thinking of using count, inner join, and group by.

CurrentLoan is current books check out and History is past books that were check out.

Goal: For each member (member ID, last name, and first name) list the number of books the member currently checked out, and the number of books the member checked out in the past. If a member checked out the same book multiple times, it will be counted multiple times. If a member has no book check out it should be counted as 0.

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE Book
    (bookID INT,
    ISBN INT,
    title varchar (30),
    author  varchar (20),
    publish_year INT,
    category varchar(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (bookID));  

CREATE TABLE Member
    (memberID INT,
    lastname varchar (20),
    firstname varchar (20),
    address varchar(20),
    phone_number INT,   
    limit_ INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (memberID));

CREATE TABLE CurrentLoan
    (memberID INT ,
    bookID INT,
    loan_date DATE,
    due_date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (memberID, bookID),
    FOREIGN KEY (memberID) REFERENCES Member(memberID),
    FOREIGN KEY (bookID) REFERENCES Book(bookID));

CREATE TABLE History
    (memberID INT,
    bookID INT,
    loan_date DATE,
    return_date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (memberID, bookID, loan_date),
    FOREIGN KEY (memberID) REFERENCES Member(memberID),
    FOREIGN KEY (bookID) REFERENCES Book(bookID));

INSERT INTO Book VALUES (10, 1113312336, 'The Dog', 'Jack Crow', 1990, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (12, 2221254896, 'Worms', 'Jim Kan', 2013, 'childrens');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (13, 3332546987, 'Crow', 'Jan Flo', 2000, 'fiction'); 
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (14, 4443456215, 'Big Dog', 'Lan Big', 1993, 'childrens');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (15, 5552314569, 'Green Apple', 'Theo Brown', 1978, 'childrens');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (16, 6664581631, 'Red Bean', 'Khang Nk', 2017, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (17, 7771452369, 'XML and XQuery', 'Author Le', 2017, 'non-fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (18, 8881245525, 'The Dark Room', 'Jack Se', 2017, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (19, 9991123546, 'Yellow Bird', 'Jake Red', 2014, 'reference');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (20, 1122112356, 'XQuery: The XML Query Language', 'Heart Le', 2002, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES (21, 1212121212, 'The Giving Tree', 'Shel Silverstein', 1964, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES (22, 2121212121, 'Gone Fishing', 'Shel Silverstein', 1964, 'reference');
INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES (23, 1313131313, 'The Lazy Dog', 'Jake Red', 2016, 'childrens');
INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES (24, 3131313131, 'The Red Bird', 'Jake Red', 2016, 'childrens');
INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES (25, 1414141414, 'The Very Blue Boy', 'Ben Jen', 2006, 'fiction');

INSERT INTO Member VALUES (001, 'Lee', 'Nancy', 'Brownlea Drive', 1254896325, 10);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (002, 'Le', 'Ray', '10th Street', 1234561256, 2);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (003, 'Kan', 'Charlie', '5th Street', 1234567236, 8);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (004, 'Brown', 'Joe', 'Elm Street', 1234567845, 9);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (005, 'Smith', 'John', '33 East', 1234567890, 3);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (006, 'Khang', 'Nkaujyi', '358 Spencer', 2145345625, 5);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (007, 'Jones', 'David', '4th Street', 14812365789, 10);
INSERT INTO Member values (008, 'Lee', 'Tou', 'Lee Street', 2145632562, 1);
INSERT INTO Member values (009, 'Jones', 'John', '1st Street', 0124789541, 7);

INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (006, 17, '14-FEB-17', '12-MAR-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (004, 17, '12-OCT-17', '09-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (004, 20, '12-OCT-17', '09-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (005, 18, '13-APR-17', '12-MAY-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (007, 25, '02-OCT-17', '25-DEC-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (008, 15, '03-MAY-17', '08-AUG-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (008, 12, '03-MAY-17', '08-AUG-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (009, 12, '02-OCT-17', '23-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (009, 14, '23-JUN-17', '24-OCT-17');

INSERT INTO History VALUES (008, 12, '03-JAN-16', '25-MAY-16');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (008, 15, '03-JAN-16', '25-MAY-16');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (009, 20, '12-FEB-16', '05-MAY-16');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (009, 15, '12-JUN-16', '05-AUG-16');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (006, 20, '14-MAY-16', '04-DEC-16');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (007, 12, '02-OCT-16', '25-DEC-16');
COMMIT;
```

This is what I have so far, Query:

```
SELECT Member.memberID, lastname, firstname, COUNT (CurrentLoan.bookID) as numberofbooks
FROM Member
INNER JOIN CurrentLoan ON Member.memberID = CurrentLoan.memberID
INNER JOIN Book ON CurrentLoan.bookID = Book.bookID
GROUP BY Member.memberID, lastname, firstname
```

This is what I want the output to be:

```
memberID    lastname    firstname    numberofbooks
1           Lee         Nancy        0
2           Le          Ray          0
3           Kan         Charlie      0
4           Brown       Joe          2
5           Smith       John         1
6           Khang       Nkaujyi      2
7           Jones       David        2
8           Lee         Tou          4
9           Jones       John         4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To arrive at zeros in the count columns, you need NULLs in the data because COUNT() does NOT increment by 1 for NULL but will increment on any NON-NULL value. To get NULLs into the result use OUTER joins (here they are LEFT OUTER JOINs).

```
SELECT Member.memberID, lastname, firstname, COUNT (CurrentLoan.bookID) as Current_
FROM Member
LEFT OUTER JOIN CurrentLoan ON Member.memberID = CurrentLoan.memberID
/* LEFT OUTER JOIN Book ON CurrentLoan.bookID = Book.bookID */
GROUP BY Member.memberID, lastname, firstname
ORDER BY Member.memberID, lastname, firstname
```

nb: You don't need the second left join unless you are going to use some column from that table.

**See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aa53f/2)**

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aa53f/2/0)**:

```
| MEMBERID | LASTNAME | FIRSTNAME | CURRENT_ |
|----------|----------|-----------|----------|
|        1 |      Lee |     Nancy |        0 |
|        2 |       Le |       Ray |        0 |
|        3 |      Kan |   Charlie |        0 |
|        4 |    Brown |       Joe |        2 |
|        5 |    Smith |      John |        1 |
|        6 |    Khang |   Nkaujyi |        1 |
|        7 |    Jones |     David |        1 |
|        8 |      Lee |       Tou |        2 |
|        9 |    Jones |      John |        2 |
```

**with History**

```
SELECT Member.memberID, lastname, firstname, COUNT (Loans.bookID) as Count_All
FROM Member
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      select memberID, bookID from CurrentLoan 
      union all
      select memberID, bookID from History 
     ) loans ON Member.memberID = Loans.memberID
/* LEFT OUTER JOIN Book ON CurrentLoan.bookID = Book.bookID */
GROUP BY Member.memberID, lastname, firstname
ORDER BY Member.memberID, lastname, firstname
```

Comment: but it only works with current, where history (past)? it should be able to get the total number of books for a member with current and history.

Comment: goodness, why not try something yourself, much better way to learn, but in a moment I will add the missing join and count

Comment: I've been doing this question for almost 4 hours and couldn't get it.

Comment: Instead of left outer join could you have use full outer join and it will still work? i try it and it seem to work.

Comment: Yes it will still work, but there is no need for it; full outer join is more "costly" than "left outer join" `and it won't improve the results at all`.

Comment: you could try doing the grouping before the join (i.e. join a subquery of the unioned loans tables) and that "might" be more efficient

Answer (score 1):

Comparison for fun: see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aa53f/10

```
SELECT Member.memberID, lastname, firstname, COUNT (Loans.bookID) as Count_All
FROM Member
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      select memberID, bookID from CurrentLoan 
      union all
      select memberID, bookID from History 
     ) loans ON Member.memberID = Loans.memberID
GROUP BY Member.memberID, lastname, firstname
ORDER BY Member.memberID, lastname, firstname
;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                  | Name        | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |             |   15 |   945 |    9 | 00:00:01 |
|   1 |   SORT GROUP BY            |             |   15 |   945 |    9 | 00:00:01 |
| * 2 |    HASH JOIN OUTER         |             |   15 |   945 |    8 | 00:00:01 |
|   3 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL      | MEMBER      |    9 |   333 |    3 | 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     VIEW                   |             |   15 |   390 |    4 | 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      UNION-ALL             |             |      |       |      |          |
|   6 |       INDEX FAST FULL SCAN | SYS_C007213 |    9 |   234 |    2 | 00:00:01 |
|   7 |       INDEX FAST FULL SCAN | SYS_C007216 |    6 |   156 |    2 | 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 2 - access("MEMBER"."MEMBERID"="LOANS"."MEMBERID"(+))
```

now try it thi way:

```
SELECT Member.memberID, lastname, firstname, NVL(Loans.Count_All,0) Count_All
FROM Member
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      select memberID, count(bookID) as Count_All
      from (
            select memberID, bookID from CurrentLoan 
            union all
            select memberID, bookID from History 
            ) l
      GROUP BY memberID
     ) loans ON Member.memberID = Loans.memberID
ORDER BY Member.memberID, lastname, firstname
;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name        | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |             |   15 |   945 |   10 | 00:00:01 |
|   1 |   SORT ORDER BY              |             |   15 |   945 |   10 | 00:00:01 |
| * 2 |    HASH JOIN OUTER           |             |   15 |   945 |    9 | 00:00:01 |
|   3 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL        | MEMBER      |    9 |   333 |    3 | 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     VIEW                     |             |   15 |   390 |    5 | 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      HASH GROUP BY           |             |   15 |   390 |    5 | 00:00:01 |
|   6 |       VIEW                   |             |   15 |   390 |    4 | 00:00:01 |
|   7 |        UNION-ALL             |             |      |       |      |          |
|   8 |         INDEX FAST FULL SCAN | SYS_C007213 |    9 |   234 |    2 | 00:00:01 |
|   9 |         INDEX FAST FULL SCAN | SYS_C007216 |    6 |   156 |    2 | 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 2 - access("MEMBER"."MEMBERID"="LOANS"."MEMBERID"(+))
```

so, in this test second method not better...